# importing error in python while importing two classes

Tags: python, sqlite

I am working with a python script, and i face importing problem when i try to import a class from another python script. Here is how my python project folder looks:

```
Mysql_Main/ 
          checks.py
          Analyzer/
                  config.py
                  ip.py
                  op.py
                  __init__.py
```

Now i want to import two classes named: Config() and Sqlite() from config.py into the checks.py script.How do i do it?

This is what i tried, but its resulting in an error!

inside checks.py:

```
from Analyzer import config

config = config.Config()
sqlite = config.Sqlite()
```

The problem is that Config class is imported properly, but Sqlite class is not getting imported.It is showing error - Config instance has no attribute 'Sqlite'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do:

```
config = config.Config()
```

You write over the variable `config` and it no longer points to the **module** `config`. It stores the new `Config` **instance**.

Try:

```
from Analyzer import config

config_instance = config.Config()
sqlite_instance = config.Sqlite()
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input! I interchanged the two statements instead of changing its name, it worked!

Comment: You won't be able to use the `config` module that way and it may seem unreadable for people who are not familiar with your code. You can try something like `from Analyzer import config as configmodule`